# Python Game Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having a problem with my game here are the functions I think are causing the problem

```
def move(self):

        self.canvas.move(self.Oball,self.move_x,0)
        if self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)[0] <= 0:
            self.move_x = 1
        elif self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)[2] >= 700:
            self.move_x = -1



def EatBall(self):

    if self.canvas.coords(self.ball) == self.canvas.coords(ball1.Oball):
        canvas.delete(ball1.Oball)
        self.PlayerWon += 1

    elif self.canvas.coords(self.ball) == self.canvas.coords(ball2.Oball):
        canvas.delete(ball2.Oball)
        self.PlayerWon += 1

    elif self.canvas.coords(self.ball) == self.canvas.coords(ball3.Oball):
        canvas.delete(ball3.Oball)
        self.PlayerWon += 1

    if self.PlayerWon == 3:
        time2 = time()
        TimeItTook = time2 - self.time1
        canvas.create_text(350,100,text="You Won",font=("Arial",22))
        canvas.create_text(350,200,text="It took you %s seconds to eat all the balls" % int(TimeItTook),font=("Arial",18))
        self.PlayerWon = 10
```

The Line "if self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)[0] <= 0:" is returning a error and it causes the game to crash. 
Also I am having a problem in the Eatball function.
In the function the variable self.PlayerWon is not increasing every time a ball is eaten.
I am a noob at coding so the code may be messy
Please help me fix this

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- there is absolutely no reason any SO question should ever begin, "I am writing a [large project]. Here is the entire codebase."

Answer (score 0):

the reason

> The Line "if self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)[0] <= 0:" is returning a
>   error and it causes the game to crash

is that after a ball was eaten, the self.canvas.coords(self.Oball) returns None, then it will raise `index out of range` exception

so you can just change your code like this

```
border = self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)
if border and self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)[0] <= 0:
    self.move_x = 1
elif border and self.canvas.coords(self.Oball)[2] >= 700:
    self.move_x = -1
```

and you say

> the variable self.PlayerWon is not increasing every time a ball is
>   eaten

because every time it assign to 0, so you should put the `self.PlayerWon = 0` in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my program but I do not exactly understand how you fixed it. All you did was add a border variable and checked if it's 0 index value was less than or equal to 0. Could you please explain why this code works

Comment: @Crafterguy  `if border` checked if it's None.